# Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert SafeERC20: low-level call failed

Tags: token, solidity, remix, decentralized-applications

I have written a smart contract which the purpose of swapping via 1inch exchange. I have deployed the contract to a locally forked mainnet using ganache-cli and successfully pre-funded my contract. However, when executing the swap function, the transaction reverts with the following message: **Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert SafeERC20: low-level call failed**. This is the code I am having problems with:

```
function swapOnOneInch(
    address fromToken,
    address toToken,
    uint256 originAmount,
    uint256 minTargetAmount,
    uint256[] memory exchangeDistribution
    ) internal {
    uint minOut = 99 * minTargetAmount / 100;
    bytes memory _data = abi.encodeWithSignature(
      "swap(address,address,uint256,uint256,uint256[],uint256)",
      fromToken,
      toToken,
      originAmount,
      // Set to 99% of the minTargetAmount, to give us a
      // 1% price/slippage buffer
      minOut,
      exchangeDistribution,
      0
    );
    invoke(0x50FDA034C0Ce7a8f7EFDAebDA7Aa7cA21CC1267e, _data);
}
```

I have been looking all around the internet and could not find a useful solution. Does someone understand where the error might be? Any help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You must approve the 1Split address before calling swap. You may also need to approve the 1SplitWrap contract address.